# load multiple file in node js by express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

how to load html file along with css file and javascrip file in node js by express?
when I enter localhost:8080\about, load the about us page that contain html,css and js.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

for that in your main express js file, you are going to want to add this line at the top of the file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pathToStaticFiles'));
```

pathToStaticFiles will be the path to your static file, (usually called assets or public).  Then all your html files will read from that directory so if your file path for the css file is ./static/css/style.css the html file will call from ./css/style.css.  Hope this helped.